# How to rebase when with local changes

Tags: git

I like `git pull --rebase`, but it doesn't work when there are local changes. So I wrote a script (named `safepull`) to stash the local changes while the rebase is running:

```
git stash push -m 'Hide from pull-rebase'
git pull --rebase
git stash pop
```

However, if by chance there are no local changes, `git stash push` does nothing, but `git pull` still takes an existing stash entry and applies it, and it's almost certainly an unwanted one.

How can I `pull --rebase` regardless of whether there are local changes or not? I thought of forcing `git stash push` to create an empty stash entry, but apparently there is no way to do it. `git`'s exit code is zero (success) regardless of whether a stash entry was created or not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sure looks like it does :)